# How can I Use 2 databases with one WordPress install

Tags: php, mysql

What I'd like to do is have the regular WordPress application run from its regular database, and then have a separate database for a game server which will hold all game data.

What I need is to make a connection between the two so when someone signs up through WordPress, it automagically registers them in the game database as well.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: "best" for whom, where and when? There isn't enough details here to even speculate....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [user_register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register%20%22user_register%22%20hook) hook to capture user information after their details are saved to the database.

Comment: I believe this is what I'm looking for, will have to give it a try and see. Thank you!